# UltiSnips requires py >= 2.6 or any py3

Tags: vim, python-2.7

I'm trying to install UltiSnips in different way but the same message appears each time when I launch vim.
Python 2.7 is installed but it seems that vim has been installed before the 2.7 version.

I tryed to reinstall vim using this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim):

```
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial libssl-dev
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim
$ hg clone http://hg.debian.org/hg/pkg-vim/vim
$ cd vim
$ hg checkout unstable
$ debian/rules update-orig
$ dpkg-buildpackage -i -I
$ cd ..
```

But the same problem remains.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't provide much information to help. You can check whether your Vim has Python via `:py print "yes"`. For the Python version, check the `:version` output. It will contain something like `-lpython2.7`.

When you compile Vim yourself, you need to enable the Python integration by passing `./configure --enable-pythoninterp`.

Comment: Vim has not python -lpython doesn't appears and :py command does not recognize. I tried to reinstall (download into vim dir and make install) but same thing.

Comment: Then `./configure` probably doesn't detect Python, or are you building the _tiny_ version of Vim (which doesn't have any language integrations)? Why don't you just use the default Vim packages of your distribution? At least on Ubuntu, the default Vim packages come with Python support.

Comment: Because it's a group account (work computer) created quickly on Debian. Now it's work. I had to add option on `./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config`

Comment: Yes, that invocation is missing in your question; glad you've figured it out!

Comment: After installing `vim-gtk-py2`, the error message is gone.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with NeoVim on Ubuntu. Running `:CheckHealth` pointed me into the right direction. Creating the following softlink solved the problem for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe obvious to most, but not to me was the fact that the `neovim` module had to be installed. On ubuntu, installing it using `pip` did the trick for me:

```
sudo pip3 install neovim
```

To install the module for python 3, I suppose pip3 has to exchanged for pip for python 2.

Answer (score 2):

Download the source code from http://www.vim.org/.
Then

1. cd vim
2. make clean
3. ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-multibyte --with-vim-name=vim --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu
4. make
5. sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing UltiSnips, my simple solution was to type inside vim `:version` where `python3` wasn't install. I solve this installing vim-gtk3, try `sudo apt install vim-gtk3` after installing gtk3 the message disapper and my vim launches normally ;)